# How do I loop my entire program?

Tags: python

How do I make my code go back to the fifth line and ask the player for another character? I need to make the  player able to enter as many characters as they want.

```
  from __future__ import division #This imports the division module which allows the program to generate decimals
from random import randint  # This imports the random integer module which allows the program to randomly generate integers


character = raw_input(str("Pick a character: martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))   # This asks the player what character they would like to play
strength = randint(3, 20)  # This sets the range for the strength variable
speed = randint(3, 20)  # This sets the range for the speed variable
height = randint(120, 183)/100   # This sets the range for the height variable (the variables are 100x the amount that the task states) it then divides the value by 100
#  The reason as to why the height value is 100x what it is meant to be is because the height is a decimal and the randint function only works with real numbers
heart_rate = randint(60, 110)  # This sets the range for the heart rate variable


if character=="martian":  # This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "martian"
    strength += 3  #This adds 3 to the value of strength
    speed +=2 #This adds 2 to the value of speed
if character =="plutonian":  #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "plutonian"
    heart_rate+=7 #This adds 7 to the value of heart rate
    height+=1 #This adds 1 to the value of height
if character=="human": #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "human"
    heart_rate+=3 #This adds 3 to the heart rate value
if character=="dog": #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs dog
    height-=3 #This takes 3 away from the height value


print "Your strength is", strength  # This prints the strength of the character
print "Your speed is", speed  # This prints the speed of the character
print "Your heart rate is", heart_rate  # This prints the heart rate of the character
print "Your height is", height  # This prints the height of the character


file_txt=open('Character Statistics.txt', 'a',) #This creates and names the text file
file_txt.write(str("Character Statistics:\n")) #This makes a title within the text document
file_txt.write("Your strength is: ") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(strength)+"\n") #This adds the strength value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your speed is: ") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(speed)+"\n") #This adds the speed value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your heart rate is: ")  #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(heart_rate)+"\n") #This adds the heart rate value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your height is is: ") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(height)+"\n") #This adds the height value to the txt file
```

Comment: Put the loop around the logic you want to loop. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: Put the entire logic within loop. Also I suggest to post it on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) . There is a lot to improve in this code snippet

Comment: create a function (or, even better) a class for characters.

Comment: Can't see "fifth line" or any user input being taken in your code, but wherever that line is, some form of a `while` or `for` statement would accomplish a loop. Checkout https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: What ceejeyoz already said; you pretty much already solved the problem yourself. A "loop" is what you need, so figure out how to do that in python, write it, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` loop:

```
character_list = ['martian', 'plutonian', 'human', 'dog']
while True:
    character = raw_input("Pick a character: %s\n>>" % ', '.join(character_list))
    if character not in character_list:
        # The user is done
        break
```

If the user enters an invalid character, assume they are done and break out of the loop. Put the rest of your character generation code after the `if` stanza.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.